# OpenVPN and specifying client IP's

Tags: configuration, openvpn

I have set up an OpenVPN network with a number of clients. To assign an IP address to my clients, for each of the clients I create a `client` file in the `ccd` directory on the VPN server that contains a line such as this:

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.5 10.8.0.6
```

This works well in principle but once you get past a few clients, creating a file for each of them that contains an IP address becomes quite cumbersome, not to mention, chaotic since you lose oversight on which client has which IP address assigned.

Is there a different way, e.g. a single file, in which I can specify the IP addresses for each of my VPN clients?

Answer (score 1):

A work-around would be a configuration management system like Puppet or Ansible, where you would specify the addresses in a single configuration file, and then would run the software which would then generate the actual files.